# Sending signal in Special Time like hh:mm with Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to send a signal in special time like every day in 22:23 o'clock with Qt Library.
I want to use something like this function:

```
QTimer::singleShot("22:23", this, SLOT(updateCaption()));
```

I don't want to use `if` statements in my code and check time. i mean:

```
if( time == "22:23" )
    emit mysignal();
```

how is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I'd do this.

First, get the datetime of the next time you want to emit the signal:

```
auto then = QDateTime::currentDateTime();
auto setTime = QTime::fromString("22:23", "hh:mm");
if(then.time() > setTime){
    then = then.addDays(1);
}
then.setTime(setTime);
```

calculate the time difference from now

```
auto diff = QDateTime::currentDateTime().msecsTo(then);
```

and start a singleshot timer at that time, to start the regular daily timer:

```
QTimer::singleShot(diff, [this]{
    auto t = new QTimer(QCoreApplication::instance());
    connect(t, &QTimer::timeout, [this]{
        emit mysignal();
    });
    t->start(24 * 3600 * 1000);
});
```

Note that this will be an hour off when the daylight saving time changes.

Comment: If you wish to fix the part about being off when crossing a daylight saving boundary, you can use this library for the time computation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vwd3pduVGKY&t=27m30s  And here are links showing how to convert back and forth between this library and `QDate`:  https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/wiki/Examples-and-Recipes#QDate  Extending that conversion to include time-of-day should be straightforward.

Comment: @HowardHinnant , there is no need to use any external library if one is using Qt. `QDateTime` already takes [DST into account](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetime.html#daylight-saving-time-dst).

Comment: @Mike:  Ok, cool.  The author of this question said otherwise, and I don't have Qt installed to check for myself.  There aren't many date/time libraries that allow you to do local time arithmetic across DST boundaries and have it come out right.  Most only support UTC time arithmetic across DST boundaries.  The docs at the link you give don't differentiate between these two operations. If you're not sure what I mean, the youtube link I give above points directly to the part of my talk explaining the difference, and even uses the same duration (1 day) as is used in this answer (by coincidence).

Comment: @HowardHinnant the issue isn't with `QDateTime`, but with the fact that I'm using a dumb 24hour timer. If I re-set the timer every time it hit the `timeout()` for that `QTime` of tomorrow, it'd be fine across DST and timezones (at least as fine as `QDateTime` is).

Answer (score 0):

I've done a brief search and found this solution, looks pretty smooth:

```
QDateTime now = QDateTime::currentDateTime();
QDateTime timeoftheaction = ...;
QTimer *timer=new QTimer;
connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()),object,SLOT(action);
timer->start(now.secsTo(timeoftheaction)*1000);
```

Of course you can write a function and call it with the single line

Comment: It's not good solution, because i want to send signal in 22:23, if current time = 22:22. then send a signal every one minute.

Comment: @hassanpanahi indeed, but you can fix it by replacing connect by singleshot